# Target one class of those specified with CSS

Tags: css

I have a div element which has 3 classes:

```
<div class='captcha_article captcha_email captcha_register'></div>
```

How can I target the third class for example, without affecting the style of the other two classes in the div?

Also, if I were to have 4 classes, how to target the last one without using `last-child` property ? Would `:nth-child` apply here?

Comment: You want to target the third element with those classes (or) the third class among `captcha_article captcha_email captcha_register` (which would be `captcha_register`)?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the `nth-child` and `last-child` selectors - they've got nothing to do with the list of classes. Order of classes is interchangeable.

Comment: @Harry the third class `captcha_register`, or the second class `captcha_email`

Comment: Just use `.captcha_register` then, unless I misunderstand.

Comment: Your element will pick up the styles applied by any of the three classes; if you don't want it to pick up styles from `captcha_article` or `captcha_email`, then don't add those classes to the div in question.

Comment: @MrLister I have tried that, however the styles I apply will also affect `captcha_article` and `captcha_email`. I would like to apply a set of rules only to a specific class in that list, while the other classes remain unaffected.

Comment: It doesn't work that way. Does David's answer help? Otherwise, it may just be matter of nomenclature. Can you whip up some html and css that shows the problem you're having?

Comment: @MrLister Would the comment from David's answer help?

Comment: CSS selectors target *elements*. A class is just a means to identify a set of elements. If you target an element that is a member of one class, the fact it is also a member of some other classes doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You misunderstand CSS.

You can add styles to the captcha_register class by doing this in your CSS file.

```
.captcha_register {
    // Attributes go here
}
```

Depending on where this is placed in your CSS file will determine if any of the style attributes adding to the captcha_article and captcha_email classes will be affected.

For example:

```
.captcha_article {
    height: 200px;
}

.captcha_register {
    height: 100px; // This will override the height of 200px on the div
}
```

UPDATE

If each class is suppose to represent a different web page then adding them all to the same element might explain why you are seeing unexpected results. It might be better to combine the styles that appear in all classes into one reusable class, lets call it .page. Then on each page you use this you can modify it with another class, if it needs to be modified.

Comment: I think my problem lays in the fact that I have three different pages which are picking up these classes, so each class represents a different web page.
I used the attributes in the order that they appear:
`div.captcha_article, div.captcha_email {margin: 0%}` while 
`div.captcha_register {margin: 10%}` - I need the last class to have a different margin than the other two. Is this achievable?

Comment: Like David says, put the overriding one later in the CSS file. So it should work, what you have. If it doesn't, please show an example that demonstrates the issue. Edit your question and create a snippet.

Comment: Thank you both, I was able to figure it out with your suggestions.